# Gatling resources with feeder

Tags: resources, gatling

I'm trying to use a feeder in a resource however on the subpage I get a

No attribute named 'searchCriterion' is defined

The second one is found however. How do I use a feeder in a resource?

```
    object Search {
      val feeder = csv("search.csv").random

      val search = group("mygroup") {
        exec(http("Home")
          .get("/")
          .resources(http("subpage")
            .get("/subpage")
            .queryParam("""f""", "${searchCriterion}")))
          .feed(feeder)
          .exec(http("Search")
            .get("/computers")
            .queryParam("""f""", "${searchCriterion}")
            )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem as nothing to do with resources: you're trying to use the `searchCriterion` attribute BEFORE actually setting it!

Move the `feed` call BEFORE the `exec(http("Home")...)` block